# Nginx : why 400 bad request happend?

Tags: python, django, macos, nginx, uwsgi

I'm doing build my own django server with nginx and uwsgi.
i almost done but 400 Bad Request always appear...
what am i wrong?

```
[info] 61794#0: *35 client sent invalid method while reading client request line, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "
                                                                                                                                                      QUERY_STRINGREQUEST_METHODGET
                                                                                                                                                                    CONTENT_TYPECONTENT_LENGTH
                                                                                                                                                                                                             REQUEST_URI/   PATH_INFO/"
```

this is error.log(info)

and this is .conf file

```
upstream django {
        #server localhost:9001;
        server unix://~/Desktop/fido_virtual/fido.sock;
}

server {
        listen 8999;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;

        client_max_body_size 75M;

        location /media {
                alias ~/Desktop/fido_virtual/media/;
        }
        location /static {
                alias ~/Desktop/fido_virtual/fidoproject/staticfiles/;
        }

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                include /usr/local/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

this .conf in project folder

```
upstream django {
        #server localhost:9001;
        server unix:///Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/fido.sock;
}

server {
        listen 8999;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;

        client_max_body_size 75M;

        location /media {
                alias /Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/media/;
        }
        location /static {
                alias /Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/fidoproject/staticfiles;
        }

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                #include /Users/junbeomkwak/Desktop/fido_virtual/fidoproject/uwsgi_params;
                include /usr/local/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

this file is in /usr/local/etc/nginx/site-enabled/.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  /var/log/errorngnix.log  info;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    include       mime.types;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
/ssl
 ⚡️   /usr/local/etc/nginx  cd ..

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  /var/log/errorngnix.log  info;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    include       mime.types;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
```

and this is /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

what is my mistake?... help me